# Why is 'I wonder if [...] ?' used to form questions?

Tags: grammaticality, questions

I have noticed that many users on this site start a question with *I wonder if* and then go on to finish with a question mark, presumably inflecting strangely at the end.

Is this an acceptable use of a question mark, or is it bad grammar?

Whence does it come?

Comment: This is what is known as an "indirect question"; a speech act that is intended to be interpreted as a question, but is shaped like some other kind of speech act, partly to ameliorate the imposition, and partly to express deference. There is a big literature about them, starting with [Gordon and Lakoff 1971](https://books.google.com/books?id=SJXr9w_lVLUC&pg=PA271&lpg=PA271&dq=gordon+lakoff+conversational+postulates&source=bl&ots=V8ZX_sKeR0&sig=ADq0ZVFaG7oy5uHVCac77tWSxAM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4gaqpl_fPAhUrilQKHbgeC1QQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=gordon%20lakoff%20conversational%20postulates&f=false)

Comment: @JohnLawler Great, can you create an answer out of that, it seems it might answer the question fully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct punctuation for an indirect question?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24614/what-is-the-correct-punctuation-for-an-indirect-question)

Comment: How is the sentence spoken?  Punctuation primarily provides non-syntactic clues to how a sentence is to be spoken.  A question mark implies that the sentence is spoken with the sort of rising intonation at the end that signals a question.

Comment: Consider that "That's a horse?" may be a legitimate question (if, eg, the speaker was just shown a picture of a cow and was told it's a horse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Chicago Manual of Style*, along with many other style guides and websites, says no:

> 6.68 Indirect questions
> An indirect question never takes a question mark.
>
> He wondered whether it was worth the risk.

But the example sentences at [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wonder) show that many people do place a question mark there. See Verb 1.1.
Examples:

> ‘I wonder whether you have thought more about it?’
>
> ‘I've been considering my last question, and I wondered whether the church in the photograph is in Venice?’

But note that are just as many examples that don't have a question mark.

I would be surprised if people who use a question mark in such indirect questions actually use a rising intonation when saying the sentence.

Comment: I can see the first example (OD verb 1.1)  with "wonder" and a high rising terminal, but I have doubts about the second sentence with "wondered".

Comment: I never would...

Answer (score 0):

If is used to introduce a subordinate clause. So it is grammatical.
You have subject = I, verb = wonder, and a subordinate clause, functioning as a direct object, introduced by the conjunction if. 
The whole sentence functioning as a question can be attributed to the verb wonder which indicates curiosity about something mixed with doubt.

Declarative sentences can be used as questions in the English language. See [English Syntax and Argumentation](http://stiba-malang.ac.id/uploadbank/pustaka/MKLINGUISTIK/ENG%20SYNTAX%20BOOK.pdf) Section 4.3.5 The Pragmatics of The Sentence Types

Comment: This seems good but I wonder if you have any references? (I felt dirty typing that.)

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey what do you want a reference to? The first part is a grammatical analysis of the sentence into Subject + verb + Direct Object. Then an explanation of the "if" conjunction. After that some semantics. And at the end, a statement that about the use of declarative sentences. All of this is from syntax theory.

Comment: You can back up the claim that declarative sentences can be used as questions?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I added a reference to a textbook on Syntactic Theory that supports this claim. I use that textbook when I need to brush up on syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your improvement. I still feel that converting a sentence such as an "*I wonder if*" into a question isn't grammatical. Obviously, like my comment above, they are intelligible, but are they commonly used - not just colloquially - to form questions? Your reference says that "*You haven't closed the door?*" is pragmatically a question (undeniable) but syntactically not. I would like to know whether it should then end with a question mark. Look at my last sentence, should that end in a question mark? It is pragmatically a sentence but syntactically not.

Comment: I see. I am not sure about whether to use a question mark or a full stop at the end. I don't have any reference for that nor any knowledge.

Comment: If you can't answer it, vote it up so someone who can will see! :)

Comment: That was a joke, wasn't it? "You can back up the claim that declarative sentences can be used as questions?" is a declarative sentence used as a question, isn't it?

After the use of the question mark in the first place, the second thing to learn about questions in English - and most other languages I've ever heard - is that it's impossible to find anything that can't be turned into a question through intonation…

What did I miss there, Guys?